# ASP.NET Core Razor Page create new for list always give System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

when I open create new items open this page to enter the values for save to list
but I always get null also inside the item there is group of item i show as drop list also give null error

**in view**

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Items.Id" />
<label asp-for="@Model.Items.Groups.Id">Group nme</label>
        <select asp-for="@Model.Items.Groups.Id"  asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.AllGroup,"Id","GroupName" ))"></select>
```

**in CS file**

```
    public class Items_Class
    {
        public int Id  { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemQuantity { get; set; }
        public Groups_Class Groups { get; set; }
    }


    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
       private readonly Groups_Methods g_Mrthod;

       [BindProperty]
       public Items_Class Items { get; set; }
       public List<Groups_Class> AllGroup { get; set; }
       
       public CreateModel(Groups_Methods  G_Mrthod)
       {
            g_Mrthod = G_Mrthod;
          
       }    
    

       public void OnGet()
       {
           AllGroup = g_Mrthod.GetAllGroups();        
       }
   }
```

Comment: welcome to SO, your `Items` property is not set, this might cause your `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I've hard time to understand your problem. What are the steps?

- Load the page
- Add new item
- Save
- Server side has null values in ItemName, ItemPrice and ItemQuantity
  If these are the steps, please consider adding a

`public void OnPost()`
and read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set your `Items` and `AllGroup` :

```
[BindProperty]
        public Items_Class Items { get; set; } = new Items_Class();
        public List<Groups_Class> AllGroup { get; set; } = new List<Groups_Class>();
```

If it still doesn't work,try to check if `g_Mrthod.GetAllGroups();`  is null.